# Unable to click a generated element?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to design a simple game but I've encountered an issue that got me stuck for hours despite trying various methods hence, unable to move on.
The game I'm creating is basically by selecting the correct input number, I would gain a point. However, if I click onto the wrong number the points would decrease.

The issue is as follows: 
-> After creating a generated random number of integer 1-9, I am unable to click the generated number to gain or decrease a point.

```js
var choosenNumber;

function startGame() 
{ 
  choosenNumber = prompt("Please choose a number between 1-9");
  document.getElementById("answer1").innerHTML = choosenNumber;
  var blinkNumbers = setInterval(autoNumbers, 1000);
  
}

function autoNumbers() 
{
  document.getElementById("randomNumber").innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
  document.getElementById("randomNumber2").innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random()* 10);
  document.getElementById("randomNumber3").innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random()* 10);
  
}

function pointSystem()
{
 var x ;
 if (x == choosenNumber)
  document.getElementById("score1").innerHTML = "" + 1 ;
}
```

```html
<div id="a"> 
  <button onClick="startGame()">Start Game</button>
  <button onClick="stopGame()">Stop Game</button> <br />

  <span>Your chosen number is:</span>&nbsp;<span id="answer1"></span><br />
  <span>Your score so far:</span><span id="score1"></span><br />

  <span id="randomNumber" onClick="pointSystem()" style="color:red; font-size:70px"></span> 
  <span id="randomNumber2" onClick="pointSystem()" style="color:orange; font-size:70px"></span> 
  <span id="randomNumber3" onClick="pointSystem()" style="color:blue; font-size:70px"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: please explain you game a little more. So we could help

Comment: well first there is no defined stopGame() function.

Comment: @MaheerAli sure, sorry for the lack of content in my explanation. If u tried to run my snipet, it will prompt u to input a number from 1-9. For example I will chose 2 as my input number, it will appear as : Your choosen number is: 2. Now, there will be 3 randomly generated number that appear below. What i want to solve is, by clicking "2" on the randomly generated numbers, i will gain a point. However, if I click on any number other than 2, i will decrease a point. Hope this is clearer for u. :)

Comment: I see what the issue is, does it have to be JS or is jquery ok?

Comment: @ptts hi! The stopGame() will be added later on as it should not be a problem for me. :) and only JS please, as I am new and want to take things step by step.

Comment: @Keith Lim check my answer

Comment: @MaheerAli Thanks! It works! NowI just have to take some time to slowly breakdown to see how its done. Cheers and good day ahead!

Comment: @Keith Lim i have added a little explanation and links to documentation. Accept the answer if you are satisfied

Comment: @Keith Lim why not accepted my answer it works fine

Comment: @MaheerAli hi sorry didn't realize there is a button to accept ans. Have alr done it. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `class="randomNumber"` to each span of blinking Numbers. Then use **[Document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)** to access them and iterate through **[addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)** which call the `pointSystem()`. I also added variable `score`.

```js
var choosenNumber;
//this contain score
var score = 0;
document.querySelectorAll('.randomNumber').forEach(span =>{
  //e.target.innerHTML is innerHTML of 'span' clicked
  span.addEventListener('click', (e) => pointSystem(e.target.innerHTML))
})
function startGame() 
{ 
  choosenNumber = prompt("Please choose a number between 1-9");
  document.getElementById("answer1").innerHTML = choosenNumber;
  var blinkNumbers = setInterval(autoNumbers, 1000);
  
}

function autoNumbers() 
{
  document.getElementById("randomNumber").innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
  document.getElementById("randomNumber2").innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random()* 10);
  document.getElementById("randomNumber3").innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random()* 10);
  
}

function pointSystem(num)
{
 //num will be the innerHTML of span clicked what we passed into the function from event listener which is e.target.innerHTML
 if (num == choosenNumber){
  //increase score by 1
  score++;
  document.getElementById("score1").innerHTML = score;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="a"> 
  <button onClick="startGame()">Start Game</button>
  <button onClick="stopGame()">Stop Game</button> <br />

  <span>Your chosen number is:</span>&nbsp;<span id="answer1"></span><br />
  <span>Your score so far:</span><span id="score1"></span><br />

  <span id="randomNumber" style="color:red; font-size:70px"></span> 
  <span id="randomNumber2" style="color:orange; font-size:70px" class="randomNumber"></span> 
  <span id="randomNumber3" style="color:blue; font-size:70px" class="randomNumber"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I took some liberty with your little project, i would do it a bit like this (with jquery)

https://jsfiddle.net/7c0y9u84/20/

```
let choosenNumber;
let blinkNumbers;
let score = 0;

$('#start-button').click(() => {
    if (blinkNumbers === undefined) {
    choosenNumber = prompt("Please choose a number between 1-9");
    $('#answer1').html(choosenNumber);
    blinkNumbers = setInterval(() => {
      $('#randomNumber1').html(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10));
      $('#randomNumber2').html(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10));
      $('#randomNumber3').html(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10));
    }, 1000);
  }
});

$('#stop-button').click(() => {
    clearInterval(blinkNumbers);
  blinkNumbers = undefined;
});

function pointSystem(number) {
  if (number == choosenNumber) {
    score++;
  } else {
    score--;
  }
  $('#score1').html(score);
}

$('#randomNumber1').click(() => {
    pointSystem($('#randomNumber1').text());
});
$('#randomNumber2').click(() => {
    pointSystem($('#randomNumber2').text());
});
$('#randomNumber3').click(() => {
    pointSystem($('#randomNumber3').text());
});
```

Comment: Hi Vajura, thanks for the input but unfortunately I've yet to step into the world of JQuery, is it possible to solve this purely with JS?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an event Listener with callback fn to the generated element.
Either assign the same class to them, then add the listener by iterating over the nodeList.

I have only removed one inline JS for the demo.

The whole JS

```
 function pointSystem(numberPassed)   {// user input as argument
  var score = 0;// define score
  var output = 
  document.getElementById("score1");// cache the output element
  output.innerText = " " + score; // use innerTEXT, innerHTML removes eventListeners!
  console.log(score); // checking
  if (numberPassed === choosenNumber){
  score++;
  output.innerText = score;
   }
   }
```

That should do, here is the codepen

https://codepen.io/damPop/pen/JxMPBv?editors=0010

Comment: your code is not adding score. Declare `score` in global scope